# Analytics data shows in App Center for Android version of Xamarin Forms project but not iOS

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin-forms-4

I'm not seeing any analytics data in App Center in the iOS version of my Xamarin Forms project. Android works as expected.

I've looked on the StackOverflow site and on the Microsoft site for help but haven't found anything that fixes my problem.

I don't see the "App Center SDK configured successfully" mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/troubleshooting/ios. Not sure if I'm not looking in the right place for it. I looked in output window.

I've set the log levels to verbose as well.

Any ideas why the iOS version isn't working? Thanks